# How to install X11/xorg?

Tags: xorg, software-installation

My 12.04 x64 system won't boot into GUI, but I can still use virtual console with my own account, so apparently it's the Windows Management System that's causing it, how can I reinstall it from tty, what's the `apt-get` command?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Please refer to [ServerGUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI).

The answer is to use this commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
```

Answer (score 30):

**X11 Client Installation**

To do this, install the xauth pachage, then install the applications you need, and apt-get will bring in other packages as needed to satisfy the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
```

**X11 Server Installation**

To install a minimal X11 on Ubuntu Server Edition enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo apt-get install openbox
```

Answer (score 10):

If you certainly have run into this problem , type in the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and you are good to go. The statements from top to bottom are dependencies to the statements after them.

Answer (score 4):

do nothing. just relax. And if you don't find out how to install, I will tell you:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using:

```
sudo aptitude install xorg
```

then say 'yes' to the updates.