# How can I install an absolute minimal install of X11 on Ubuntu Server 12.04?

Tags: xorg, software-installation

I'm hesitant about installing X11 on a server machine because I want it to contain the absolute minimal amount of software needed.

However, some GUIs (for FFMPEG encoding, etc) are useful so I was thinking about installing X11.

What is the absolutely minimum number of packages I would need to install in order to run some simple (?) GUIs like the frontends for FFMPEG, etc.  I don't think I need a window manager or anything else, etc.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-12-04-lts-x64