# Stuck in Unity 2d, 12.04

Tags: unity, apt

Since applying some fixes to Ubuntu 12.04 after being horribly stuck, I noticed when I login to Unity 3D, I enter Unity 2D (both entries are available at login). Unity 3D seems to be completely missing.

- `nick@nick:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` shows:

  > Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
  >   Error: GLX is not available on the system
- Unity 3D worked perfectly before.

My technical knowledge is limited so I find it hard to compare my question with those already asked on the site. Additional info about what happened before this issue came up may be due to some chaotic removal and installation of stuff without reasons I understand. [Info here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387643/cant-start-ubuntu-12-04-in-gui) and maybe this sheds some light. I *did* reïnstall the packages marked as **remove**:

> Start-Date: 2013-12-07  02:00:03
>   Commandline: apt-get install libqt4-dev intltool
>
> Install: libx11-xcb-dev:amd64 (1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2, automatic), libxdamage-dev:amd64 (1.1.3-2build1, automatic), libqt4-opengl-dev:amd64 (4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4, automatic), libpthread-stubs0:amd64 (0.3-3, automatic), libxfixes-dev:amd64 (5.0-4ubuntu4.1, automatic), libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (9.2.0~git20131002+9.2.2eb55601-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (1.12.3+git20120709+server-1.12-branch.60e0d205-0ubuntu0ricotz~precise, automatic), libxcb-dri2-0-dev:amd64 (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2, automatic), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (9.2.0~git20131002+9.2.2eb55601-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (9.2.0~git20131002+9.2.2eb55601-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (9.2.0~git20131002+9.2.2eb55601-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), libglapi-mesa:i386 (9.2.0~git20131002+9.2.2eb55601-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), libxxf86vm-dev:amd64 (1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1, automatic), x11proto-kb-dev:amd64 (1.0.5-2, automatic), x11proto-gl-dev:amd64 (1.4.16-1, automatic), mesa-common-dev:amd64 (9.2.0~git20131002+9.2.2eb55601-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), xtrans-dev:amd64 (1.2.6-2, automatic), libqt4-dev:amd64 (4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4), x11proto-input-dev:amd64 (2.1.99.6-1, automatic), x11proto-fixes-dev:amd64 (5.0-2ubuntu1, automatic), xserver-xorg-input-evdev:amd64 (2.7.0+git20120504.f28507e8-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 (9.0.0-0ubuntu1~precise1, automatic), libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev:amd64 (2.3.1-2, automatic), x11proto-xext-dev:amd64 (7.2.0-3, automatic), qt4-qmake:amd64 (4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4, automatic), libxext-dev:amd64 (1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1, automatic), libxcb-glx0-dev:amd64 (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2, automatic), x11proto-damage-dev:amd64 (1.2.1-2, automatic), libqtwebkit-dev:amd64 (2.2.1-1ubuntu4, automatic), libxau-dev:amd64 (1.0.6-4, automatic), qt4-linguist-tools:amd64 (4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4, automatic), xorg-sgml-doctools:amd64 (1.10-1, automatic), libx11-dev:amd64 (1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2, automatic), libx11-doc:amd64 (1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2, automatic), libkms1:amd64 (2.4.46+git20130702.c6d73cfe-0ubuntu0sarvatt~precise, automatic), libxcb1-dev:amd64 (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2, automatic), x11proto-core-dev:amd64 (7.0.22-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), x11proto-dri2-dev:amd64 (2.8-1, automatic), libxdmcp-dev:amd64 (1.1.0-4, automatic), libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (0.3-3, automatic)
>
> Remove: xserver-common-lts-raring:amd64 (1.13.3-0ubuntu6~precise3), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.267.1), xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring:amd64 (7.7+1ubuntu4~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-raring:amd64 (12.0.2+git.e5ac80d8-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-raring:amd64 (0.7.0-0ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-raring:amd64 (7.1.0-0ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-raring:amd64 (6.9.1-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring:amd64 (1.0.7-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-raring:amd64 (1.7.2-3~precise1), x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring:amd64 (7.7~3ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-raring:amd64 (2.7.3-0ubuntu2b2~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring:amd64 (7.7+1ubuntu4~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-raring:amd64 (1.5.2-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-raring:amd64 (1.6.2-1ubuntu6~precise1), libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring:amd64 (9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1), libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring:i386 (9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-raring:amd64 (6.9.3-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring:amd64 (0.6.5-0ubuntu3~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-raring:amd64 (2.3.2-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-raring:amd64 (1.4.5-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-raring:amd64 (0.9.6-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-raring:amd64 (7.1.0-0ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-raring:amd64 (1.3.6-0ubuntu2~precise1), libxatracker1-lts-raring:amd64 (9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-raring:amd64 (0.19.0-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-raring:amd64 (1.6.2-0ubuntu1~precise1), libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring:amd64 (9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1), libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring:i386 (9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-lts-raring:amd64 (7.7+1ubuntu4~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-raring:amd64 (0.4.3-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-core-lts-raring:amd64 (1.13.3-0ubuntu6~precise3), xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-raring:amd64 (12.9.0-0ubuntu3~precise1), xorg:amd64 (7.6+12ubuntu2), xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-raring:amd64 (1.2.7-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-raring:amd64 (0.3.1-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-raring:amd64 (0.10.7-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-raring:amd64 (2.3.6-0ubuntu1~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring:amd64 (2.21.6-0ubuntu4.3~precise1), libglapi-mesa-lts-raring:amd64 (9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1), libglapi-mesa-lts-raring:i386 (9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1), xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-raring:amd64 (1.7.7-0ubuntu1~precise1)
>   End-Date: 2013-12-07  02:01:39

Very sorry for the chaotic way this looks.

Edit:
As mentioned, all the removed packages got reïnstalled. It seemed logical to run 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
like I found in the last link you provided. This gave me the output:

> Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     x11-apps linux-headers-3.2.0-56 x11-session-utils x11-xfs-utils
>     linux-headers-3.2.0-56-generic xinit libfs6 libllvm3.3
>   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
>   The following extra packages will be installed:
>     libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386
>     xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-evdev
>   Suggested packages:
>     xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
>   The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring:i386
>     libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring:i386
>     libglapi-mesa-lts-raring libglapi-mesa-lts-raring:i386
>     libxatracker1-lts-raring ubuntu-desktop x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring xorg
>     xserver-common-lts-raring xserver-xorg-core-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-sis-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-raring
>     xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-raring
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>     libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386
>     xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-evdev
>   0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 41 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 2,295 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 37.8 MB disk space will be freed.
>   Do you want to continue [Y/n]?

This scares me a lot because it says a lot of stuff will be removed. I experienced this before and it resulted in being left with CLI. Should I run it?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8545496/2943276) - GLX sort of connects OpenGL and the X Windows system. You could try installing anything related to OpenGL and glx. Also see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1741783). Have you tried re-installing what it removed *(some of it may of been removed as it was outdated...)*

Comment: I edited my post. To be honest I'm not sure that choosing Yes will be a good thing

Comment: I might've missread your comment. I will try again in the morning.

Comment: Applying 'fix' found on https://theiszm.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/glx-missing-on-display/

Comment: Could you explain me if I find the same problem how can I fix it without clicking any link?

Comment: @Braiam        I just did.

Comment: @Nkciy84 Can you cut your edit from the top of your question and put it an answer, then mark it as solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applied *fix* found on [this web-page](https://theiszm.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/glx-missing-on-display/) and thanks to [wilf](https://askubuntu.com/users/178596/wilf) for finding a way to this fix.**

How to apply the fix:

- Open your terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

*Type or copy/paste each line:*

- `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel  libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core`
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
- `sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf`

*After this I reïnstalled my nVidia software*

- `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319`

*Rebooted and everything was peachy again.*

Note that I already had Bumblebee installed beforehand.