# Remote into Desktop on Ubuntu through SSH

Tags: server, ssh, remote

So we have SSH access to a Ubuntu server, and we need to setup some programs that require visual access, but we have no clue how to do this through SSH.

Comment: First, the Ubuntu server does not have a GUI be default. If Ubuntu desktop is installed, see [How to setup x11vnc to access with graphical login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen) for Ubuntu 18.04 and above also see [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x11vnc no longer works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035598/ubuntu-18-04-lts-x11vnc-no-longer-works) x11vnc can be used through a ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

If the Ubuntu server has `X11` server running (you can check it with `echo $DISPLAY`, it should return non-empty string on success), you can forward `X11` by using

```
ssh -X me@remote-host
```

After logging in to the remote host, windows for visual programs launched there should appear as if they were launched locally.

If `X11` server is not installed in the remote machine, you can install it, i.e. you can refer to the thread here:

[How to install X11/xorg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [X2Go](https://www.x2go.org). It's basically the Teamviewer of the Linux world. It has clients that work on Windows as well. I use it to connect to all of my Linux servers. I strongly suggest configuring it to use the xfce4 desktop.