# Configure a VNC server on Ubuntu 19.10 desktop

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, vino

I am trying to set up my Ubuntu Desktop to allow me to access it from my Windows 10 laptop. I installed the latest supported version of Ubuntu and it runs very nicely from the desktop.

I simply cannot get Vino to work. To be honest it isn't totally apparent to me what I should use as the client for Vino, so I tried RealVNC. I can't even make a connection.

So then I tried the default VNC server that comes with Ubuntu. I still couldn't make a connection.

So I switched to TightVNC. Now I could make the connection but all I saw was a grey screen. So I spent hours on Google and most links suggested installing the xfce4 desktop, which I did. And it worked.

Let me just say that I did not like xfce4 very much so did an Ubuntu reinstall from scratch.

But now I am left with the same issue: I can connect but I just get a grey screen. I have seen several links that point to installing other components.

**All I want to do is display the default Ubuntu desktop on my laptop.**

Any hints for configuration of Vino, the default VNC server, or TightVNC would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have spent more hours than I would care to admit working on getting remote access working with out using ubuntu screen share from ubuntu device to ubuntu device and without using XFCE4. If you get it to work please let the rest of us know. Good luck!

Comment: The most easiest way to gain remote access to an Ubuntu (like it could be done in the case Windows-RemoteDesktop-Windows) is to use some third-party service as NoMachine, RealVNC (VNC Connect), TeamViewer (my preference). As I know all of them have free non-commercial versions.

Comment: I got X11VNC to work following two questions. First the old [guide.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen) Then an [update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035598/ubuntu-18-04-lts-x11vnc-no-longer-works) for Ubuntu 18.04.