# How to have local and remote access to same X session without a monitor always attached?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, vnc, amdgpu

On Ubuntu 20.04, I have an AMD system with an integrated GPU (Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega 8) and want to be able to access an existing running X session (whether a user is logged in or not) via both:

1. A (sometimes) connected monitor over HDMI
2. Remotely from Windows 10

Ubuntu's built-in remote desktop (`vino`) does not run before a user is logged in, so it's not viable.
So I looked into enabling `XDMCP` with `gdm` and using it directly from Windows.  After messing around with it for a while, I realized/remembered that a) XDMCP has crappy support on Windows, b) is slow, and c) is insecure

I also tried using `x11vnc`, `Xephyr`, and `Xnest` (the latter two with a Windows X Server) bound to the `gdm` login X session.  None of these worked, and I suspect the reason was that `gdm`'s login implementation does this crazy thing where it uses one X display for login and another after login.  There is a workaround to this described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036507/566303).  But that is a pain, so I decided to switch to `lightdm`, which does not have this issue.

That works fine remotely using `x11vnc` with a VNC client over SSH connecting to the existing lightdm/X session, as long as a monitor is plugged in.  Don't even need XDMCP enabled.

But then I discovered that when there is no monitor attached, although the X startup works just fine at boot, and I can get to a login screen and login, after that I am greeted with an **empty desktop with no menu bar and no menus/icons** (but it has the Focal Fossa background visible).  By the way, this is the same behavior I got with XDMCP and gdm most of the time, but that was due to it switching X displays after login.

How do I solve this?  I know I can use the `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` and that works, but then I cannot get the local/physical monitor to work at the same time even with both drivers (Devices) in my Xorg config.

I realize I could buy or make one of those [fake monitor HDMI dummy connectors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XT1Z9TF) but isn't there a software solution to this?

The `amdgpu` driver has a module option called `virtual_display`, but it disables all physical displays.
I also tried the `evdi` (evdi-dkms) virtual monitor package but it did not seem to solve this.

I prefer not to use `nomachine/nx` or `x2go` because there are not a lot of client options for every OS.
`Xpra` behaves the same way was x11vnc.

---

**Edit: ok actually I think I've narrowed down the issue to something related to `gnome/mutter`, because it does not occur with e.g. `fvwm`.**  In other words, if I just start X and run fvwm, it will work remotely via x11vnc without any special X configuration or use of dummy driver.

Also `Gnome Flashback` (installed via the `gnome-session-flashback` package and chosen using that gear-esque looking icon on the login screen) sort of works after login, but the Settings app crashes sometimes. It uses `metacity` as the window manager.