# Remote access to 14.04.2 desktop through Google's Chrome extension vs. installing X11 server?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, remote-desktop

I have an Android tablet and smartphone and there are pages of apps in Google PLAY related to remote desktop. I have Chrome installed on both my Android 4.4.2 tablet and [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/about/) 14.04.2, with the remote desktop extension for Chrome by Google installed on both machines. Is it a best practice to install the X11 server, if planning on *any* remote access to Linux?

[How to install X11/xorg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has a built in VNC server. search for screen sharing and configure. which is better, is a matter of which performs more practically for you. VNC will be compatible with many of the Android apps, if you want remote access outside of your home network don't forget to forward TCP port 5900 in your router to your computer

Comment: If Ubuntu has it, then xubuntu should at least be able to install the VNC server. Is there a situation where it's a good idea to install the X11 server package?

Comment: I can't recommend it only because I have never had to use it, VNC works with every platform like Android, Windows, OS X and IOS. I hope my answers were helpful

Comment: Is there a VNC client app to connect to the VNC server for Android?

Comment: remote2go supports VNC and RDP