# I can't compile x11 aplication

Tags: compiling

How do I get `Xm/CutPaste.h`?
Google gives only x11 documentation.
And I don't know how to get needed libraries

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out what package has a specific file, you can install `apt-file`.  For example,

```
$ sudo apt install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ sudo apt-file search Xm/CutPaste.h
libmotif-dev: /usr/include/Xm/CutPaste.h
```

So, to answer your question, the `libmotif-dev` package has the file `Xm/CutPaste.h`.  I'm not sure if that's the file you're looking for, of course.  It's just matching by filename.

Oh, and this was for Ubuntu 22.04.  You didn't mention what version of Ubuntu you're on.

Comment: how to install the whole x11

Comment: @alexsoftoficial Oh?  That's a separate question...  If that's what you want to know, you probably should post a new question, explaining which version of Ubuntu you are on.  This is an [old](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg) answer, but perhaps it could help you get started.  If it isn't good enough, you might want to start with a new question.