Cannot open some apps (Nautilus). Wayland-nvidia package fixes but causes lag. Xorg not working. What to try next?
This problem seemingly started randomly for me the other day where I cannot use Nautilus file manager or other apps like the Settings app in Ubuntu 24.04. I found my first answer here: Ubuntu 24.04 with Nvidia driver "libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen". However this library libnvidia-egl-wayland1 causes other apps to have significant graphical and input lag (VSCode, Slack).
A potential fix seemed to be to switch to X11 however this option does not exist in the cog icon on start-up. The flag, DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop, provided here Set "Ubuntu On Xorg" by default globally but without preventing the choice of Wayland does not work and setting WaylandEnable=False causes the system to fail to boot. I have installed all the xorg related packages (https://askubuntu.com/a/326676/1915534), but this problem persists.
Looking for a solution to have these apps work and not to have horrendous lag in my other apps.
Ubuntu: 24.04.1 LTS
Host: Blade 16 - RZ09-0483 9.04
Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic
Packages: 1968 (dpkg), 11 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.2.21
Resolution: 3840x2400
DE: GNOME 46.0
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: 13th Gen Intel i9-13950HX (32) @ 5.300GHz
GPU: NVIDIA Laptop 4090 GN21-X11\

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please edit the question and add this info.
